# JINJA2 HMTL SUSTITUTION

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm testing a little code to work, but I can't get it to work, this is the flask/python part:

```
#from weasyprint import HTML
import flask
import os
##
##html = HTML('text.html')
##html.write_pdf('invoice.pdf')

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    today = datetime.today().strftime("%B %-d, %Y")
    navigation = [1,2,3]
    return flask.render_template('text.html',navigation = navigation,fecha = today)

 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

this is the test html, that im trying to work on:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        welcome {{fecha}}
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        {% for item in navigation %}
            this is a test, and hello {{item}}world!!!
        {% endfor %}
    </body>

</html>
```

but the output is this :

```
welcome {{fecha}} {% for item in navigation %}this is a test, and hello {{item}}world!!! 
{% endfor %}""" (brs a let out intetionally)
```

this is the current folder structure:

[image]

what am I missing to make this work as intended?

Comment: can you also post the image of your folder structure??

Comment: it is something like this (idk how to post images here sorry) 
C:\Users\xxxx\jinja test (folder)
app.py
templates (folder)
   text.html

Comment: use `PrtSc` button on your keyboard then use `Ctrl` + `V` here.

Comment: i tried that, but, this box doesnt seem to acept the image

Comment: not on this box in your **POST**

Answer (score 0):

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    fruits = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    return render_template('index.html', fruits = fruits)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Your `.html` files should be in `templates` folder otherwise it will not work. **(CASE SENSITIVE)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Flask App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for fruit in fruits %}
        <li>{{ fruit }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Folder Structure**

[image: Folder Structure]

**Output Image**

[image: Result]

Comment: it is inside templates

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: nope, i still get the same text

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: is the .py inside templates?

Comment: ummm i see your file is running on "LocalHost", but mine isn't launching, im just opening tha .html as a normal files, i guess thats where i should look at

Comment: good lord, that was it, i was openning direcly the .html, insted of going to the "server" address.

Comment: Finally you got it. 

Comment: was about time.